# Reading a txt with spaces ( c++)

Tags: c++, text-files

I am trying to read a .txt file, in my text file there are numbers but also path folders ( for example : "C:\Documents and Settings......" )

I am able to read the numbers withouth any problem, but when I try to read the paths, I just read until the first ‘space’, it means, I just read in both cases “C:\Documents”. What could I do?

```
//READING PARAMETERS FROM A .TXT FILE
//double sigma; double alpha; double tau;
//double miniter; double maxiter; double q; double m;
//‘R’ image folder ; ‘T’ image folder; 

// input-file-stream
//  - in = (input) open the file for reading
ifstream f ( "parametros.txt", ifstream::in ) ; 

// Error if it is not open properly
if ( !f){
    cout<<"ERROR OPENING THE FILE .TXT"<<endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


char *cadena = new char [100];
stringstream  folder_T; 
stringstream  folder_R;
int iter = 1;
while ( !f.eof() ){
    // reading the next line
    f >> cadena ;
    if ( iter == 1 ){
        sigma = atof(cadena);
    }
    else if ( iter == 2){
        alpha = atof(cadena);
    }
    else if ( iter == 3){
        tau = atof(cadena);
    }
    else if ( iter == 4){
        miniter = atof(cadena);
    }
    else if ( iter == 5){
        maxiter = atof(cadena);
    }
    else if ( iter == 6){
        q = atof(cadena);
    }
    else if ( iter == 7){
        m = atof(cadena);
    }       
    else if ( iter == 8){
        folder_T<<gets(cadena);      // Only “C:/Documents”  is returned
    }
    else if ( iter == 9){
        folder_R<<gets(cadena);      // Only “C:/Documents” is returned
    }

    iter = iter + 1;

}// fin while
f.close();
```

Comment: have you heard about switch statement? read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0t5wee3(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: [`while (!f.eof())` is almost always wrong](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.5). Where did you learn to do that?

Comment: While-if pattern, may I ask you to consider why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not reading a complete line into `cadena`. Do this

```
getline(f, cadena);
```

Also, you shouldnt be using `gets()`. You would already have the complete line in `cadena`.

Comment: And expanding just a little bit: while (f.getline(cadena, sizeof(cadena)) { ... }